# Is it possible to convert xml file into data frame in pandas?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have an xml file. I tried to convert this xml file into data frame. But I could not.

**XMl Input**

```
<root>
    <note>
      <to>Tove</to>
      <from>Jani</from>
      <heading>Reminder</heading>
      <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
    </note>
    <note>
      <to>Tove</to>
      <from>Jani</from>
      <heading>Reminder</heading>
      <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
    </note>
</root>
```

**Expected Output**

```
id    to      from    heading    body
0    Tove    Jani    Reminder   Don't forget me this weekend!
1    Tove    Jani    Reminder   Don't forget me this weekend!
```

Answer (score 1):

See below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

xml = '''<root>
    <note>
      <to>Tove</to>
      <from>Jani</from>
      <heading>Reminder</heading>
      <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
    </note>
    <note>
      <to>Tove</to>
      <from>Jani</from>
      <heading>Reminder</heading>
      <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
    </note>
</root>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
data = []
for note in root.findall('.//note'):
    data.append({e.tag: e.text for e in list(note)})
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

output

```
                            body  from   heading    to
0  Don't forget me this weekend!  Jani  Reminder  Tove
1  Don't forget me this weekend!  Jani  Reminder  Tove
```